# B-Tree Node References its "Parent"

Tags: b-tree

I have a very simple question about B-Tree nodes:

**Is it conceptually accurate/correct that a B-Tree node references its "parent node" or the node that contains the pointer to it?**

I have been looking into different B-Tree implementations and none of them includes a reference to the parent node in the class that represents the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/user/gamadrid/nscript/btreep.h, which defines a node as:

```
typedef struct node {
  struct node *parent;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
} *btnode;
```

Not a b-tree, but the principle is the same.

The Parent pointer is just there as a convenience, much like a doubly-linked linked list allows you to traverse it both ways without requiring that you maintain a stack of pointers to the previous nodes like a singly-linked list does.

Without the parent pointer, you simply traverse the tree using a recursive function.  The call stack keeps track of where you are in the tree.

Comment: Yes, i know that i can add a reference to the parent node. However, is the reference to the parent part of the definition of the B-Tree node or this is only a technical possibility?

Comment: It is part of the definition, not a hypothetical.  How else would you build the tree vertically?

Comment: Are you sure that the definition you quoted is for a B-Tree node? I know the B-Tree node includes a list of sub keys and pointers and not only a right and left nodes, right?

Comment: It claims it is.  Hold on, I'll just write one.

Comment: Yes, my question basically is this: is it "safe", for the B-Tree to function, to ignore that a B-Tree node references its parent?

Comment: I think it is, yes.  The Parent pointer is just there as a convenience, much like a doubly-linked linked list allows you to traverse it both ways without requiring that you maintain a stack of pointers to the previous nodes like a singly-linked list does.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please post this as an answer or edit this one before i mark it?